# How can I create a Drupal "Page" (not a block) without any theme?

Tags: 6, theming

How can I create a Drupal "Page" (not a block) without any theme?
I do not want this "Page" to include any header / footer / left / right column.
My understanding is that this isn't possible but could I create an additional theme for my site which is just completely blank, and apply this to the appropriate pages?
We have a salesman that wants to build his own set of pages within Dreamwever and then I would apply this blank theme against just these pages without impacting the existing theme that is utilized for the other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user is going to create pages in Dreamweaver, then just have him upload the files into a subfolder of the Drupal root directory...and they will load completely independent of Drupal.

IE:

Drupal Directory == /foo/bar/htdocs/mydrupalsite
Drupal URL == blah.com/mydrupalsite

User's DW files directory == /foo/bar/htdocs/mydrupalsite/dwsite
User's DW URL == blah.com/mydrupalsite/dwsite

His pages will not be affected by Drupal at all. You just have to be careful when upgrading/updating that you leave his folder structure intact.

With this method, you don't have to do any htaccess redirects or anything like that.

Comment: It is better to find a way to work with Drupal than to fight it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.

This module has a number of really useful options; relevant to your question, you can have it use a different theme or a stripped down version of your existing theme on certain paths or conditions.